# parse catched error body as ReadableStream in axios in react

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, axios

i sent a post request with axios in react form to php server. after that i tried to catch error, but it returns ReadableStream in it's body:

[image]

but in postman i have no problem and i receive errors readable:

[image]

how can i receive errors like postman. readable.

here is my code :

```
try {
   const response = await axios.post(url,body,config);
   console.log(response.status)
} catch (error) {
   // i need readable errors here
   console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i parsed readable stream using following function:

```
const parseReadableStreamToJson = async (error) => {
    const data = (await error.getReader().read()).value
    const str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, data);
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

function usage:

```
try {
   const response = await axios.post(url,body,config);
   console.log(response.status)
} catch (error) {
   const errs = await parseReadableStreamToJson(error.body);
   console.log(errs);
}
```